# Whats the recommended way to handle the Apple's "Data use & sharing" warning message?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I just got mail from Apple stating that

> **"Data use & sharing"** : Your app uses analytics software to collect and send user or device data to a third party without the user's consent. Apps must request explicit user consent and provide a clear visual indication when recording, logging, or otherwise making a record of user activity. This includes any use of the device camera, microphone, or other user inputs.
>
> For your app to remain available on the App Store, you must remove any code, frameworks, or SDKs that collect, record or share a users data and resubmit your app for review.

Please let us know what is the recommended way to handle it,

My suggestions:

1. Can we just remove the data tracking(only for analytics & statistics which is the key to business) 3rd party SDKs ?

   (or)
2. Just add permission alert stating that we are collecting information for so and so permission and track information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has started a crackdown on the apps which tracks user activity through user inputs, screen recording etc.
The best way to get your app approved is to remove any code or the third party sdks which tracks user activity. I resubmitted an app today by removing a third party library and it got approved right away.

But if statistics are the key to your business then you can take a hint from here.

> Apps must request explicit user consent and provide a clear visual indication when recording, logging, or otherwise making a record of user activity.

If you use your own privacy policy then clearly state how you track your user and how user's data will be used. And in addition to that, also show some kind of alert in your app that how the user data will be used (maybe through a UIPageViewController)

Comment: Thank you, as of now I too have removed the 3rd party libraries and got approved since the time duration given by Apple is too less. Sooner I too will make explicit consent from user and make use of analytics.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up keeping all of our analytics (MixPanel, Google, Crashlytics, Facebook, AppsFlyer).

We only removed AppSee - because of the screen recording, and got approved within 10 hours.

My conclusion is that the only thing to remove is the screen recoding and all he rest can remain as is.

Comment: We too kept all our analytics remain except the "Inapptics" in our case.